# How do I send my Spring Boot to someone?

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-boot

Hi. I'm studying Java Web and created an application using Spring Boot and Maven.
The application is working fine using *mvn spring-boot:run*.
How do I compile or build it to send it to someone?

Hi. I'm studying Java Web and created an application using Spring Boot and Maven.
The application is working fine using *mvn spring-boot:run*.
How do I compile or build it to send it to someone?

(I'm not sure why Stackoverflow is asking for more commentary)
pom.xml

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>Paulo</groupId>
  <artifactId>Patients</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>

  <name>Patients</name>
  <description></description>

  <parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.9.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
  </parent>


  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>mysql</groupId>
      <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
      <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
      <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
      <version>4.3.11.Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
      <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
      <version>4.3.11.Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
      <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
      <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>  
  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
 <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
 <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>


</project>
```

Comment: Can you share your `pom.xml`?

Comment: @AtaurRahmanMunna pom.xml included

Comment: You can execute mvn package and send the resulting jar if you want to share just the application from a user perspective or share your code into github, for example, if you want to share also your code. What is your purpose?

Comment: @DaniloGomes I want to share in a way the other person can "plug and play". Sorry if it doesn't make sense, I just started studying Java.

Comment: Hey, no problem. But it is exactly as @AtaurRahmanMunna and I mentioned, you should execute mvn package and share the resulting jar in the target folder.

Comment: @DaniloGomes Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your `pom.xml` if `spring-boot-maven-plugin` is not available then first make sure that, it is available in your `pom.xml`(you already do that).

Spring-boot project outcome is a simple jar file. This jar file include all the file it needed, embedded tomcat etc.
Go to your project directory from command line. Say for example your project root folder name is `ABC`, then go to `/ABC` folder and run the command.

```
mvn package
```

After running this command successfully, you find a folder named `/target`. Inside the `/target` folder your find your jar file. Run the jar using `java -jar ABC.jar` command or share your jar with others.

Comment: Thank you. It has some errors, but it's a scope for a different question.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to create an installer for your application you can use 
[IzPack Maven Plugin](https://izpack.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/IZPACK/pages/491576/Compiling+Using+Maven)